# Can't sign in with app

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login, ios-app

I have had the app working for a couple months. After I recently updated the app, it won't let me sign in with Gmail nor via stackexchange. I get the following error.

> Loading the site list failed with the following errors: (null)

It also said that if the problems persist to let the site know on meta

Comment: I believe this will be better answered at the general meta page as it affects the app and is not Quant-specific.

Comment: What app? android or iOS? What device do you have?

Comment: @ShadowWizard it is called `Stack Exchange` for `iOS` . I am currently on iPhone 5s

Comment: @Jason thanks, you can login here with the same provider you're using on http://quant.stackexchange.com so that your accounts will be associated then you can edit the details into the question itself.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am getting the same error on the app, yet everytime I get a response on this questions I receive a Notification on my phone... as if i am signed in but it wont let me see the activity ( as I am answering from my computer).

Comment: @ShadowWizard I just had to delete & re-download the app and it worked!

Comment: Cheers, consider adding this as answer. :)

Comment: If you are receiving the errors just delete the app & re-download it from the App Store & sign on with your logins & it should work again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving the errors just delete the app & re-download it from the App Store & sign on with your logins & it should work again.